# Some installed applications fail to start after fresh install of 22.04.1

Tags: snap

I have a fresh installation of 22.04.1 LTS

Some pre-installed applications will not start, such as Firefox. Launching it from the gui, the mouse pointer turns into a rotating disc as if it's launching, but it never starts. If I run `firefox` from a terminal I get:

> `/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope is not a snap cgroup`

The same thing happens if I remove the application and reinstall it.

I have also installed other applications such as chromium, and the same thing happens.

Other apps such as Libre Office work OK.

`XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` is

> `ubuntu:GNOME`

---

Update:

I tried to run firefox as root and received these errors:

```
(process:15651): dconf-WARNING **: 16:02:43.610: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

Comment: What you should do after installing is to make sure the system is fully updated. You can and should use the Updates tool as it updates both debs and snaps.

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes I always do that, that with `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get upgrade` and then a reboot. It didn't change the behaviour.

Comment: `apt-get` or `apt` (preferred since many years ago) DON'T update snaps, hence why I explicitly mentioned the Updates tool that does that or, more precisely, `sudo apt full-upgrade` AND `sudo snap refresh`.

Comment: @Quasímodo I tried that and got: `firefox removed`, then `firefox 103.0.2-1 from Mozilla✓ installed` then, sadly when I run `firefox` I still get `/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope is not a snap cgroup`

Comment: @ChanganAuto running full upgrade returned `0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.`, then running `sudo snap refresh` returned `All snaps up to date.`, and the problem continues.